# How can i activate the alpha on Blender Render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I already activated the transparency, the alpha, what i'm missing? if i see the texture preview it looks like it doesnt have a background, but when i render it it still appears.
Help please!

[image]

Comment: @poor They're not using Cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable it in the Material settings:

[image: Transparency Options]

Tick the *Transparency* checkbox and set the *Alpha* value to `0`.

Also be sure to make that the texture *Influence* affects the *Alpha* value:

[image: Influence Alpha]

Comment: Already added that setting, with the difference that the Specular, Fresnel and Blend are in gray..

Comment: Do you have anything affecting the Transparency value (i.e. a texture?)

Comment: Hmm, is a simple image texture, with the Transparency value activated on Material options, and alpha activated on the Texture options, also it's shadeless.

Comment: Wait i just activated the Alpha on the Diffuse setting on 'Texture' and it worked o.O

Comment: Exactly, you need to tell Blender what texture (if any) is affecting the Alpha.